Do my avd really need 2 types of images : .img and .img.qcow2?
I noticed that many of my avds have two different image files:

an .img
an .img.qcow2

I have two hypotheses:

Andrdoid Studio changed the way of creating avd
I caused this when I switched from the old qemu floating window to the internal avd management

Is any of these hypotheses true?
If so, which file can I safely delete, if any ? They start taking a lot of space on my drive.
